# How do I determine the resultant permittivity of two different dielectric materials in a cylinder capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, charge

[image: Cylinder capacitor]

I am trying to calculate the density charge of the inner cylinder in the above picture.
If there was only one dielectric I would use the following equation:

$$
\frac{q_{enc}^f}{L} = \frac{2\pi \varepsilon_0 \varepsilon_r V (r_a)}{\ln (\frac{r_b}{r_a})}
$$

But how do I calculate with \$\varepsilon_{r_{1}}\$ and \$\varepsilon_{r_{2}}\$?

Material with \$\varepsilon_{r_{1}}\$ permittivity is in the area where \$r_1 < r < r_2\$ and \$\varepsilon_{r_{2}}\$ is where \$r_2 < r < r_3\$.

Comment: Imagine a thin layer of metal on the equipotential surface that is the boundary between the two dielectrics. Now you can clearly analyse it as two capacitors in series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reduce this problem to a **series combination of two** separate cylinder capacitors.

- One with inner radius \$r_0\$, outer radius \$r_1\$ and permitivity \$\epsilon_{r1}\$ and
- the other with inner radius \$r_1\$, outer radius \$r_2\$ and permittivity \$\epsilon_{r2}\$.

Since they are in series, charge (per length) will be equal for both capacitors.